# yGuard Obfuscate code in case insensitive file system as Windows

Tags: windows, case-insensitive, yguard

I try to obfuscase my JAR file in Windows by yGuard but classes in the same package are renamed to the same name (ignored case).

Ex.:
MyCookieUtils.class => A.class
MyFormatterUtils.class => a.class

Windows can recognize only one file with name A.class or a.class in a folder, the other is overrided. So it cannot run after obfuscation code :(

Anyone can help?
Thanks

Comment: That is actually a feature. It works in a Jar file (which is the recommended way of executing a java application), but fails on Windows file systems when unpacked, which is where script kiddies try to break it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Add property language-conformity=compatible to rename tag in build file

```
<rename>
<property name="naming-scheme" value="small" />
<property name="language-conformity" value="compatible" />
</rename>
```